# Why does this example of a Canonical Interval Decomposition contain keys and leaves that are outside of the interval?

Tags: data-structures, trees

I am reading *Advanced Data Structures* by Peter Brass for self-study, and was confused about the book's example of a Canonical Interval Decomposition for the Segment Tree section (section 4.2):
[image]

So, the key 3 is halfway between 2 and 4, the key 6 is halfway between 6 and 8, and the key 9 is halfway between 8 and 10. 4 is the "missing" number of [2, 4[, 8 is the "missing number" in [4, 8[, and 10 is the "missing number" in [8, 10[. I can kind of see where they got that.

However, I'm quite confused about why numbers like 11, 12, 13, 14, and 15 occur in this at all (given that this is a representation of the interval [1, 10]). Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Assume a set $X = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of key values and a search tree $T$ for $\{−\infty\}\cup X$."

Here $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16\}$. That graph illustrates the binary search tree $T$ for $\{−\infty\}\cup X$, where each leaf represents either $-\infty$ or an element in $X$ in the natural order.

The task is to find the canonical interval decomposition of the interval $[1, 10[\ = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ with respect to that tree.

What we will get are

- the node that represents $[1,2[$,
- the node that represents $[2,4[$,
- the node that represents $[4,8[$, and
- the node that represents $[8,10[$.

---

**Exercise 1.** What is the canonical interval decomposition of the interval $[6,13[$ for the same $X$ above?

**Exercise 2.** What is the canonical interval decomposition of the interval $[-\infty,10[$ if $X=[1,10[$?

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot more sense now - I was looking at it the wrong way I guess.